Netty versions conflict with azure-identity、azure-storage-file-datalake java sdk
I am trying to implement ADLS token credential vending in my project with the following dependencies:
// 1.13.1
implementation(libs.azure.identity)
// 12.20.0
implementation(libs.azure.storage.file.datalake)

However, when I run the project, it throws an initializationError, which is caused by a Netty conflict:
{"az.sdk.message":"The following Netty versions were found on the classpath and have a mismatch with the versions used by azure-core-http-netty. If your application runs without issue this message can be ignored, otherwise please align the Netty versions used in your application. For more information, see https://aka.ms/azsdk/java/dependency/troubleshoot.","azure-netty-version":"4.1.110.Final","azure-netty-native-version":"2.0.65.Final","classpath-netty-version-io.netty:netty-common":"4.1.112.Final","classpath-netty-version-io.netty:netty-handler":"4.1.112.Final","classpath-netty-version-io.netty:netty-handler-proxy":"4.1.110.Final","classpath-netty-version-io.netty:netty-buffer":"4.1.112.Final","classpath-netty-version-io.netty:netty-codec":"4.1.112.Final","classpath-netty-version-io.netty:netty-codec-http":"4.1.112.Final","classpath-netty-version-io.netty:netty-codec-http2":"4.1.112.Final","classpath-netty-version-io.netty:netty-transport-native-unix-common":"4.1.112.Final","classpath-netty-version-io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll":"4.1.110.Final","classpath-netty-version-io.netty:netty-transport-native-kqueue":"4.1.110.Final","classpath-native-netty-version-io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static":"2.0.65.Final"}

Previously, I tried excluding azure-core-http-netty with the following configuration:
implementation(libs.azure.identity) {
  exclude(group = "com.azure", module = "azure-core-http-netty")
}
implementation(libs.azure.storage.file.datalake) {
  exclude(group = "com.azure", module = "azure-core-http-netty")
}

But this didn’t resolve the issue and caused additional bugs.
How can I correctly import these dependencies and resolve the conflict?
And I really want to know, how to debug this and find the solution.
My project classpath dependencies
https://gist.github.com/orenccl/0c4ef46e22b0fb1f80bb16d3979d381b
Seems like azure sdk must use netty 4.1.110, but my other module also must use 4.1.112
Can I require them use different version and not conflict?
P.S. My project use java 8, so I can not upgrade azure sdk version

Is there any dependency  azure-core-http-netty  in your project?

Use the latest dependency in your project <dependency>     <groupId>com.azure</groupId>     <artifactId>azure-core-http-netty</artifactId>     <version>1.15.7</version> </dependency>

I didn't use azure-core-http-netty in my project.
Should I exclude them, and import newest azure-core-http-netty?

GIve a try or include latest version.

Try and fail. By the way my project is java8 so I can't use latest dependency. I try azure-core-http-netty = "1.14.2".

I think that is something to do with project default netty.


Netty versions conflict with azure-identity、azure-storage-file-datalake java sdk.

According to this Document(1.14.2)

Upgraded Netty dependencies from  4.1.101.Final  to  4.1.108.Final.


Seems like azure sdk must use netty 4.1.110, but my other module also must use 4.1.112
Can I require them use different version and not conflict?

You can use Shadow to handle multiple versions of Netty in your project by either relocating conflicting versions or forcing a single version across all dependencies. This approach will help resolve the version conflicts and allow your project to run smoothly.
If azure-sdk requires Netty 4.1.110, you can shade Netty 4.1.112 used by another library.
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'com.github.xxxx.shadow' version '8.1.1'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.azure:azure-storage-file-datalake:12.20.0'
    implementation 'com.azure:azure-identity:1.13.1'
    // Other dependencies
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
        if (details.requested.group == 'io.netty') {
            details.useVersion '4.1.112.Final'  // Force the desired Netty version
        }
    }
}

shadowJar {
    relocate 'io.netty', 'com.yourcompany.shadow.netty'  // Relocate Netty to avoid conflicts
    mergeServiceFiles()
}

Check the below reference like same as your error.
References:

[BUG] azure-core-http-netty 1.14.2 contains wrong netty.version property · Issue #39583 · Azure/azure-sdk-for-java
[BUG] azure-core-http-netty 1.15.1 contains wrong netty.version property · Issue #40732 · Azure/azure-sdk-for-java
java - Multiple dependency versions with Gradle 5 - Stack Overflow

